# What RNG(random number generator) algorithm suits for poker cards shuffle?

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle, poker

I'm coding an online poker game. The shuffling part is using Fisher Yates algorithm. But I have no idea which random number generator to generate good unpredictable random numbers for the shuffling algorithm to use. 
52 cards have 52! ~= 8.065e67 possible sequences.

Comment: I've googled a lot. but didn't find any useful information.

Comment: For a simple game, the entropy from  `System.Random` should be Ok. When the stakes are high and you want absolute security, use `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`. It may take a little more CPU though.

Comment: I'm building an online Texas Hold'em poker game. So I need a high quality random number generator algorithm.

Comment: Define 'high quality'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think he wants to minimize the chance of "tricky" players to get extra information from the hidden cards.

Comment: Can generator unpredictable random numbers or have a longer period than 52!.

Comment: @peterh Yes, What all I wanna do is to generate  a shuffled deck of cards and makes it very unpredictable.

Comment: Since only a vanishingly small percentage of 52! decks would ever be used (even if all 7 billion people on the planet do nothing but play your game every waking second for the rest of their lives) I don't see how a period longer than 52! is genuinely relevant.

Comment: If you are worried that an online player might be able to detect what pseudo-RNG algorithm (System.Random, say) you are using and therefore can predict what the next random number that the game uses will be, you can do what all modern slot machines do: Run the random number generator in an infinite loop on a background thread and then pull the current random number from there whenever you need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8e+67` is a lot big number, but it is not very high in data size. It is only 226 bit in data length. 28 bytes.

You may consider using a CSPRNG, *a cryptographically strong pseudorandom generator*, i.e. an RNG which generates enough strong randomness to be usable for cryptography.

Sometimes also the CPU has a true random number source, it is fast. Here I describe the CSPRNG.

On Linux, you can simply read out the random bytes from the `/dev/urandom` character device file.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Is a 256bits PRNG algorithm suitable for this purpose?

Comment: @clicli Yes. Best if you reinitialize it with some true random source (for example, by any millisecond-precision timestamp), I think it will be okay.

Comment: Could you suggest me some proper algorithm for this? I'm not professional on this area. Thanks.

Comment: @clicli You don't need to know them, they are provided by your framework. You can develop your own one, but if you aren't a professional, it surely won't be so good as the ones already built in into your framework. Furthermore, as your goal is to produce a poker game, also it won't be effective.

Comment: The game I'm coding is a browser based web game. The server side programming language is Elixir. I searched a lot. but didn't find any PRNG suitable for this.

Comment: @clicli Your question doesn't name the technologies you use, this is the frame in which you got your answer: you got technology-agnostic answers. Changing your question to contain already your technology would be a too essential change. I think the best if you now wait a little bit, and then ask your question again, but this time already with naming the technology you use.

Comment: @pethrh Before I ask this question, I searched a lot. but didn't find any useful information. Elixir is a very young programming language. So I wanna find other programming language based solution that I can invoke it's functions or communicate with it.

Comment: @clicli I don't think that switching a framework only because you can't generate a random number would be a wise decision.

Comment: @pethrh The reason why I use this minority programming language is its concurrent property. It's very suitable for web games.

Comment: @clicli Sorry I don't have too much time now, but you may visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com for chit-chat. I'll be back roughly at 20:00 UTC.

Comment: @pethrh Thank you so much for your answers. :)

Comment: @clicli You may accept my answer to prevent it from future deletion.

Comment: /dev/random blocks, which is unacceptable for a simulation/game. /dev/urandom is better for those uses.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker It is true, this is why I wrote the first sentences in the post. I extended the post to mention that it works only because he doesn't want too much data. I can check the details if you wish.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Well, not too much remained original in the post now, but at least I've learned a lot :-) How about now?

Comment: Awesome. Re-reading [*Myths about /dev/urandom*](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) was a good refresher for myself, too.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, you should use one with far more than 52! possible internal states, which means 226 bits of state. There are many PRNGs that exceed this, having 1024 or more bits of state. You also want something fast, so you can simulate millions of hands. The most popular algorithm that meets these criteria is Mersenne Twister. I personally also like variants of Marsaglia's XORshift.

I generally only use hardware true RNGs (that most PCs have nowadays) for cryptography and for seeding these PRNGs, but I am told that some of the better ones are fast enough to produce values even for simulations. You'd have to look that up for your hardware.

Comment: Thank sir. I'll give it a try

Comment: Sir, Mersenne Twister, Xorshift, WELL(a newer RNG algorithm) which one is better suitable for poker shuffling?

Comment: Any of those would fine, as long as you use them correctly.